# How to know what button as selected within a frame and use its text later in tkinter?

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter

There are a lot of similar questions regarding the use of buttons as an input in tkinter. Unfortunately, I don't think the answers I read answered my particular question.

I would like to use the text of the button clicked by the user of my game to do a logic test and return another question to the user. The game will work with a sequence of these questions, and the possible answers are always "yes" and "no".

So, I need to get the text from the button clicked among the buttons present in my Button Frame. By looking at other questions here in SO, I figured out how to get the text from a **specific** button with the `my_button['text']` command. However, I need a similar method for the whole **widget**.

The game code is too big, so I made an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that I present below. The commented out part would be equivalent to the logical test I want to implement.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random

def start_game():
    n = random.sample(range(5000),1)[0]
    text_widget4.insert('1.0', '{} é um número é par?'.format(str(n)))
    #Of course, this is not working since ['text'] is an atribute of buttons, rather than widgets
    # resto = n%%2
    # if (resto==0) & (button_w4['text'] = 'Yes'):
    #     text_widget4.insert('2.0', 'Você está certo')
    # elif (resto==0) & (button_w4['text'] = 'No'):
    #     text_widget4.insert('2.0', 'Você está certo')

class Fourth_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Meu jogo')
        self.resizable(False, False)

class Button_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        #BUTTON YES
        yes_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Yes')
        yes_button.pack(side = 'left', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

        #BUTTON NO
        no_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'No')
        no_button.pack(side = 'left', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

class Quit_Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, label_1, function_1):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.label_1 = label_1
        self.function_1 = function_1

        next_button = ttk.Button(self, text = label_1, command = function_1)
        next_button.pack(side = 'top', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')

        quit_button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Quit', command = root.destroy)
        quit_button.pack(side = 'top', padx =5, pady = 5, fill = 'x')



root = Fourth_window()

text_w4 = ttk.Frame(root)
text_w4.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'both', expand = True)

text_widget4 = tk.Text(text_w4)
text_widget4.pack()

button_w4 = Button_Frame(root)
button_w4.pack(side = 'bottom')


quit_w4 = Quit_Frame(root, 'Start', start_game)
quit_w4.pack(side = 'right')

root.mainloop()
```

My real problem is to implement an executable in a GUI. Link for the executable at [github](https://github.com/lucascr91/brecht_0.0.2/blob/master/words.py)

Comment: you can use `lambda` to assign function with argument `Button(command=lamba:function("Text from button"))`. OR you can assign button as argument after creating button - `button["command"] = lambda:function(button)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lambda` to assign function with argument

```
def function(text):
    print(text)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Yes', command=lambda:function('Yes'))
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='No', command=lambda:function('No'))
button2.pack()
```

Or you can use `button` as argument after creating `button`

```
def function(widget):
    print(widget['text'])

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Yes')
button1.pack()
button1["command"] = lambda:function(button1)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='No')
button2.pack()
button2["command"] = lambda:function(button2)
```

---

**BTW:** if you will uses `lambda` in loop then you many need `lambda x=text:function(x)` because normally it doesn't copy text from `text` but it assigns reference to variable `text` and later all buttons have reference to the same variable with the same value (last value in `for`-loop)

```
def function(text):
    print(text)

buttons = []

for txt in ('Yes', 'No'):
    # problem: all buttons will print "No"
    #b = tk.Button(root, text=txt, command=(lambda:function(txt))) 

    b = tk.Button(root, text=txt, command=(lambda x=txt:function(x)))
    b.pack()
    buttons.append(b)
```

---

**BTW:** If you use `bind()` to assign `event` with function to `widget` then function automatically get `event` with information about `widget`

```
def function(event):
    #print(event)
    print(event.widget['text'])

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Yes')
button1.pack()
button1.bind('<Button-1>', function)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='No')
button2.pack()
button2.bind('<Button-1>', function)
```